# Which package versions can I use in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, npm, cloud-storage, npm-update

I want to update npm packages in a Firebase project. However I am lost about the fixed versions in `packages.json`. I guess they are there for a reason, but I have no idea why they are there now. Maybe I installed them to get around a bug? Or, is it perhaps something handled another way behind my back?

For example if I run `npm outdated` I found this (and 7 more):

```
@google-cloud/storage    1.7.0   1.7.0   3.2.1  functions
```

And in `packages.json` then of course this:

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "^1.7.0",
```

Can I just replace it with this and run `npm update`:

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "*",
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know why the versions are what they are in your packages.json? Who or what put them there in the first place?

Comment: @JJJ You are misunderstanding my question. I am asking if there is a way to know that. And how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `package.json` contains the packages that you installed and the version of these packages.

To update do the following:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install @google-cloud/storage@latest --save
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. So using `@latest --save` puts a fixed version in `packages.json`. Or, do I misunderstand?

Comment: The latest will install latest version and --save flag will add the version to the package.json